# Passing .NET string to UTF-8 char pointer and size C function

Tags: c#, .net, f#, pinvoke

I am trying to interop with a C API that looks like this:

```c
bool next(state* state, const uint8_t* input, size_t input_length, result* result);
```

`input` should be a pointer to an array of UTF-8 bytes and `input_length` is the number bytes.

How should I pass a .NET `string` object into this API?

I have identified `Marshal.ZeroFreeCoTaskMemUTF8`, but this does not return a byte count. Is this the best approach?

Additionally, the procedure `next` does not modify any of the bytes in `input`. Is it possible to execute `next` without copying all of the input data from the .NET `string` for better performance?

Comment: Do you really need the input_length parameter?

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes. This is not my API; I am only integrating onto it.

Comment: The most simple way is this https://pastebin.com/raw/EVs8ZQva note you always have to convert from Unicode to UTF8 as .NET (Windows  in general) only knows Unicode internally, but at least you do the loop only once since you pass the length in input_length

Answer (score -1):

Strings in .NET are stored as UTF16, so copying is always necessary to/from UTF8.

If you want to use pointers then you need to manually allocate the buffer and pass it in.

```cs
[DllImport("YourDll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.CDecl)]
bool next([In] in State state, IntPtr input, IntPtr input_length, [Out] out result result);
```

You can use `Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUTF8` to allocate the buffer and copy the string into it. Don't forget to free the memory in a `finally`.

```cs
var value = IntPtr.Zero;
try
{
    value = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUTF8(YourString);
    if(!next(in someState, value, (IntPtr)Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(YourString), out var result))
        throw new SomeExceptionHere();
    // etc
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(value);
}
```

---

A better option is to just pass it as a `byte[]` array.

```cs
[DllImport("YourDll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.CDecl)]
bool next([In] in State state, byte[] input, IntPtr input_length, [Out] out result result);
```

```cs
var byteString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(YourString);

if(!next(in someState, value, (IntPtr)byteString.Length, out var result))
    throw new SomeExceptionHere();
// etc
```

---

If you wanted to prevent copying then you would need to store your strings as UTF8 byte arrays in the first place. Then you can use `fixed` to get a pointer to part of the array, or just pass the whole array in as is.

Comment: Did you consider declaring the input arg as byte[] and using Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes

Comment: Depends if you want only part of the string or not.

Comment: No suggestion that the question wants that, and in any case `GetBytes` has overloads for that. Using `GetBytes` would avoid all of the manual memory allocation.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do this:

Looks like you could use [`Utf8StringMarshaller.ConvertToUnmanaged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalling.utf8stringmarshaller.converttounmanaged?view=net-7.0) but that also has the issue that you don't know the byte count. Likely it follows the null byte terminated convention.

You could find the null byte yourself using a for loop to determine the length or call [`UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding.getbytecount?view=net-7.0).

Alternately, if your strings are short, you can allocate them on the stack:

```ml
open System
open System.Text
open Microsoft.FSharp.NativeInterop

let stackString () = 
    let x = "UTF 8 String on the stack"
    let utf8 = UTF8Encoding()
    let maxCount = utf8.GetMaxByteCount(x.Length)
    let ptr = NativePtr.stackalloc<byte> maxCount
    let span = Span(NativePtr.toVoidPtr ptr, maxCount)
    let length = utf8.GetBytes(x, span)
    // Make your call here. Below code demonstrates one way to read bytes back to a string
    let x2 = utf8.GetString(ptr, length)
    x, x2, length, maxCount
```

[`GetMaxByteCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding.getmaxbytecount?view=net-7.0) is a faster but conservative way to allocate a buffer without having to encode the string twice.